Wireshark on RHEL does not show all interfaces
I'm running Wireshark as root on Rocky Linux (RHEL equivalent). Real hardware no virtualization.
The machine has two ethernet ports and two wifi controllers.  There may be bluetooth too but I'm not concerned about that.
ifconfig shows both ethernets eth0 and eth1 as UP and RUNNING.
So does ip link
But Wireshark (run as root) only shows eth2 in the list of capture interfaces.
Why?
I have no idea what to try.  I suppose I will research how Wireshark finds interfaces but I'm not going to get into the source.

Dooh!
I don't know how it happened but display of the interface was turned off in the /capture/configure/options/manage interfaces dialog.
My bad.
